# Typescript type for value used in v-for

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, typescript-eslint

Im a Vue/Typescript noob and I want to display data from firebase in my Nuxt3/Vue3/TypeScript app. I created a state ref with reactive that I want to initially be null or an empty object, and then when the data comes back from the axios call I want to update the value of the state.

That is all working fine but when I go to display the data in the template with a v-for I am getting **"Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'**. Why am I getting that and whats the solution?

Here is what I have now:

```
<template>
  <div class="pt-4">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(person, key) in state.people" :key="key">
        {{ person.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from "axios";

const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();

let state = reactive({
  people: {},
});

onMounted(async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    `${runtimeConfig.public.firebaseBaseUrl}/people.json`
  );
  console.log(res.data);
  state.people = res.data;
});
</script>
```

I tried all kinds of things but nothing seemed to fix it. The app works and runs fine but I just want to get rid of that linting error in VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because `state.people` is not typed. Therefore, typescript does not expect it to be an array of objects with a `name` property.

So add types for the reactive state, for example like that:

```js
interface State {
  people: YourPeopleStructure // change this to people's type
}

const state = reactive<State>({ // Here I assigned State as the reactive type
  people: [], // Another fix: I assume it should be an array of people? so it has to be empty **array** by default.
});
```